# Grails 3 - change default port for run-app

Tags: grails, grails-3.0

In Grails3 `grails -Dserver.port=9001 run-app` doesn't appear to work:

> I'm "getting address already bound 8080".

Any idea how to do this - ideally by passing a property to "gradle run"?

Answer (score 40):

You can use

```
server:
  port: 9001
```

in `application.yml`.

Or you can pass it via system environment. (e.g. `SERVER_PORT=9001 grails run-app`).

Answer (score 23):

```
grails run-app --port=8081
```

Or in interactive mode:

```
run-app --port=8081
```

Don't forget to use the same port when you want to stop the server:

```
stop-app --port=8081
```

I believe this feature was broken in 3.0.3 and earlier versions but it definitely works in 3.0.4.

Answer (score 4):

Accepted answer is correct. For some additional info, Grails 3 uses spring-boot and the server properties are configured by the

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties
```

class. "port" is just a property on this class which is filled from the application.yml with the prefix "server". So in addition to the port, you can set properties of this class including tomcat configuration properties and etc. To change the contextPath for instance you add

```
server: 
   contextPath: /myapp
```

to you application.yml.

Answer (score 3):

```
  server:
  port: 9809
  contextPath: '/admin/'
```

you can use this in your application.yml file

or  change the port depends on the environment for example :

```
    environments:
        test:
            grails:
                serverURL: "http://localhost:9809"
```