# Changing default server port in grails 3.0.9 in development

Tags: grails, grails-3.0

How do we change the default port 8080 to something else in Grails 3.0.9?

Comment: Have you tried `grails run-app -Dserver.port=8082`

Comment: For some reasons passing it through args was not working in my environment. Probably I will rephrase my question as an alternative to passing args. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Through command line**

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31747695/178975) has a way which works

```
grails run-app --port=8090
```

Also, while stopping

```
grails stop-app --port=8090
```

The following may or may not work depending on grails version

```
grails run-app -Dserver.port=8090
```

**Through configuration**

Say to change it to 8090, add the following snippet to grails-app/conf/application.yml

```
server:
     port: 8090
```

under

```
environments:
     development:
```

so that it looks like

```
environments:
     development:
           server:
                port: 8090
```

Comment: For most cases putting it under `environments.development` is fine but not necessary.